# Как изучать OpenGL 4.6+?

Tags: c++, opengl

Где его изучать? Я нашел немного книг по `OpenGL 3.0+ C++`. Но она же устарела...

Есть ли книги (желательно на русском) по `OpenGL 4.6 C++`? Ну или максимально актуальные. Или же есть другой вариант изучения?

Comment: https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=46952 вот все чем версия 4.6 отличается от 4.5

Comment: математика очень нужна, если хочется продвинутся дальше рисования кубов/моделек

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я нашел немного книг по OpenGL 3.0+ C++. Но она же устарела...

Я бы не парился на этот счет.

В GL 4 в основном добавили разные продвинутые фичи, которые первое время вам все равно не пригодятся. (А когда они понадобятся, о них можно отдельно почитать.)

К тому же, на некоторых древних видеокартах/видеодрайверах GL 4 не работает, так что у 3 переносимость выше.

Возможно, есть смысл вообще начать с GL 2. (Он *намного* проще, чем 3/4. В третьей версии выбросили [старый "простой" способ рисования](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline), и оставили только рисование с помощью шейдеров.)

> Есть ли книги (желательно на русском)

Есть отличный сайт, но он на английском: https://learnopengl.com/ <s>Из-за гнусного РКН может не открыться без прокси.</s> Уже открывается.

Там рассказывается про совеременный (3,4) OpenGL. Про 2 не подскажу.

> И да, знания математики насколько нужны?

Нужна линейная алгебра (векторы, матрицы, ...), особенно для GL 3/4. В туториале по ссылке основы объясняются.

Comment: @Данил наоборот, Вы уже в 6 классе знаете, зачем Вам математика, и не будете, как 95% школьников в мое время говорить: «Зачем мне это». Изучайте сами, задавайте вопросы. Изучайте английский, ибо вся актуальная литература - на нем.

Comment: Нет, я матешу люблю. Английский... У нас училка ничего не преподает и ее не увольняют... А самостоятельно тяжело. Но я его вроде норм знаю.

Comment: Перевод серии статей с learnopengl.com есть на хабре.

Comment: А за что этот сайт (learnopengl.com) "забанили"? (У них правда там вообще не все дома, они даже доки по киви из питона забанили, но все же).

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Судя по тому, что он разбанился вместе с телеграмом, видимо айпишники совпали?

Comment: А, ну может быть, может быть. ;)